# Return column names dynamically queried by sql statement for columns values that meets a certain condition for a particular record

Tags: mysql, dynamically-generated

I have a table of courses as shown below with upto 600 courses. I want to sort out column names for  field values which are NOT NULL. I am sure the query below can do the job for a few fields. I can it be done dynamically so that i dont have to write out all courses in the CASE - WHEN statement.

```
TBL_COURSES
============

| STUDENTID | MATH101 | CHEM121 | ENG101 | PHY111 | CSC121 |
|-----------|---------|---------|--------|--------|--------|
|    301    |   NULL  |    10   |   NULL |    10  |   NULL |
|    402    |   75    |   NULL  |   NULL |    10  |   75   |
|    423    |   80    |    10   |   NULL |    10  |   60   |
|    404    |   NULL  |    10   |   100  |    10  |   NULL |
|    505    |   NULL  |    10   |   NULL |    10  |   55   |
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL>
SELECT studentId, 
      (CASE WHEN MATH101 IS NOT NULL THEN 'MATH101'
            WHEN CHEM121 IS NOT NULL THEN 'CHEM121'
            WHEN ENG101 IS NOT NULL THEN 'ENG101'
            WHEN PHY111 IS NOT NULL THEN 'PHY111'
            WHEN CSC121 IS NOT NULL THEN 'CSC121'
            ELSE ''
       END) AS registered_courses
FROM tbl_courses 
WHERE studentId = 402 ;

## RESULT

| STUDENTID | REGISTERED_COURSES |
|-----------|--------------------|
|    402    |     MATH101        |
|    402    |     PHY111         |
|    402    |     CSC121         |

Comment: My OUTPUT is NOT dynamically generated, thus it may not be used in a situation where there are many tables. Any brilliant idea ???